# What is happening when you run the query "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name;"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with several columns. One of the columns is intended to be used as a boolean setup as TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0.

I accidentally discovered that if you run this query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name;
```

it returns the rows that have column_name = 1.

I am curious to know the logic that MySql is using to process this query.

Comment: If you leave off the value, it treats the criteria as a boolean expression, looking for the column to be `true` - what is `true` for a non-boolean value depends on the type.  For numbers, it is `not 0`.

Comment: I experimented more and I think your right. What's strange though, is that it will not work for varchar. I haven't tried any other data types.

Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't find any information on the behavior.

Comment: @Orbling And if you include the value, it still treats it as a boolean expression. ;)  The WHERE clause is always a boolean expression. It's just that if you don't test a condition, then what gets evaluated is whether the value by itself is true or false, since the value is the entire expression.

Comment: Yes, I know that @AdiInbar - just that it's usually obviously a boolean expression, by virtue of boolean operators returning a boolean result to the `WHERE` clause.  However in that instance, it is the result of an internal `CAST` to a boolean, using the truthy and falsey values for each datatype.

Comment: @Chris: The truthy values for a `VARCHAR` would expect to be anything other than the empty string or "0".  But as I believe MySQL has no actual boolean values, just numbers, it would cast to a `TINYINT` probably - which would mean any valid number string would convert to 1 or 0, depending on the number, anything else would be an invalid number so would end up as 0, false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the documentation says in "Select Syntax", (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

> where_condition is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected

So the simple column name is evaluated as a boolean and the corresponding rows are selected. You'll find it works for ints, too.

Comment: This makes perfect sense, I was just surprised not to be able to find any specific documentation of this behavior on the internet and the above documentation is absolutely correct but quite broad. Plus, how this plays out for string values isn't as clear as it would be for ints. The good news is, the behavior is documented now! :)